# CSS problems, divs on each other

Tags: html, css

I have several problems with my HTML and css, this is my HTML:

```
<div class="picCommnet" style="background-color:#FFF8AD; padding: 5px 0 5px 0; border: 2px dotted #d2d9e7;">
     <div style="width:20%; float:right;background-color: yellow;">
          <img src="">
     </div>
     <div style="width:75%; float:right; padding: 5px 0 5px 0; border: 2px dotted #d2d9e7;">
          <div style="width:100%; background-color: green;">
               מתן בדיקה
          </div>
          <div style="width:100%; background-color: paleturquoise;">
               check comment
          </div>
          <div style="width:100%; background-color: red;">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div style="width:5%; float:right;">
           <img src="">
      </div>
</div>
```

All css is in the style attribute of the tags, This is how I want it to be:
http://s4.postimg.org/4dl41pd9p/how_i_want.png

this is what I get instead:
http://s4.postimg.org/ggqfp9obx/what_i_get.png

As you can see, the 3 divs that suppose to be one below the other are over each other, and the text inside the divs is somehow outside of it and the divs height remains 0.

How do I fix it?

EDIT:
this is the table I've tried to add instead of the divs:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td rowspan='3'>Remove Comment Pic</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Comment UserName</td> 
         <td>Comment Text</td> 
         <td>Likes</td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td rowspan='3'>User Profile Pic</td>  
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Post a live demo or jsfiddle for quicker and most accurate responses.

Comment: this is what i got doing the table: http://s27.postimg.org/5uvuj7x9v/table_i_get.png

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way to get this layout is with a table. **Note: It is much better to do this with a Grid layout, however browser support will vary**, a table is the *most reliable* way, but is not at all the best way.

So basically, you'd have a table like this:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">Yellow box</td>
      <td>Green box</td>
      <td rowspan="3">White box</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Turquoise box</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Red box</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: for some reason also with a table all the table cells get over each other, what might cause that?

Comment: this is what i got trying to use a table: http://s27.postimg.org/5uvuj7x9v/table_i_get.png

Comment: You're still using all your styles, aren't you? Why don't people just use the code I give them before saying it doesn't work???

Comment: I have posted the code I am using in the orginial post, there are no style attributes in the table at all

Comment: Can you show a live example of what you're doing, so I can actually see what's going on?

Comment: Your `.lightbox` CSS has `line-height:0`. This will screw over ANY text you have in there.

Comment: also after removing the line-height:0 it still not showing right. you can check it on chrome or with firebug

Comment: removing the line-height:0 fixed it with the divs, but the problem remains with the table, now I'm just curious to know why

Answer (score 0):

try to put them all position:absolute. Then you can position every single one of them independently.

Comment: you mean each div? also trying to do it with a table didn't show any success, I've commented above how to see the example

Comment: yes each div. Use it with the original style with divs, not table. If you want to do it with tables, try giving each of them an id and then style them manually.